Vite v5.3.2 building for production error
During the build, I experienced the following error.
> tsc && vite build

vite v5.3.2 building for production...
    src/index.ts:1:20 - error TS6142: Module './components/Button/Button' was resolved to '/Users/myusername/photoravel-design-system/src/components/Button/Button.tsx', but '--jsx' is not set.

    1 import Button from './components/Button/Button';
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/index.ts:2:19 - error TS6142: Module './components/Input/Input' was resolved to '/Users/myusername/photoravel-design-system/src/components/Input/Input.tsx', but '--jsx' is not set.

    2 import Input from './components/Input/Input';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/index.ts:3:32 - error TS6142: Module './PhotoravelProvider' was resolved to '/Users/myusername/photoravel-design-system/src/PhotoravelProvider.tsx', but '--jsx' is not set.

    3 import PhotoravelProvider from './PhotoravelProvider';
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    ✓ 46 modules transformed.

    [vite:dts] Start generate declaration files...
    dist/index.js  82.89 kB │ gzip: 26.25 kB
    [vite:dts] Declaration files built in 456ms.

    dist/index.cjs  60.48 kB │ gzip: 22.78 kB
    ✓ built in 712ms

The version information for my project is as follows.
package.json
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/index.umd.cjs"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.11.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.13.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.13.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.3.1"
  }
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}

tsconfig.app.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",
    "types": ["vite/client", "@emotion/react/types/css-prop"],
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "emotion.d.ts", "svg.d.ts", "dist"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules"],
  "files": ["emotion.d.ts"]
}

vite.config.ts
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react',
      babel: {
        plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
      },
    }),
    dts(),
    svgr(),
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'src/index.ts',
      name: 'index',
      fileName: 'index',
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom', '@emotion/react', '@emotion/styled'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
          '@emotion/react': '@emotion/react',
          '@emotion/styled': '@emotion/styled',
        },
      },
    },
    commonjsOptions: {
      esmExternals: ['react'],
    },
  },
});

src/index.ts
import Button from './components/Button/Button';
import Input from './components/Input/Input';
import PhotoravelProvider from './PhotoravelProvider';
import theme from './styles/theme';
import convertCSS from './utils/convertCSS';

export { Button, Input, PhotoravelProvider, theme, convertCSS };

// src/PhotoravelProvider.tsx
import { Global, ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';

import globalStyles from './styles/globalStyles';
import theme from './styles/theme';

import type { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

type Props = PropsWithChildren;

const PhotoravelProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Global styles={globalStyles} />
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default PhotoravelProvider;

I tried Googling and also asked ChatGPT, copilot, but I couldn't get the answer I wanted, so I ended up asking questions while translating to Stack Overflow.
I'd like to know the cause of this error and how to solve it.

How is Vite supposed to know you want it to use tsconfig.app.json?

Try updating the dts plugin to latest. It solved the problem to me.
I am using:
"vite-plugin-dts": "^4.0.0-beta.1"


Yes, that fixed this issue for me. But I ran into another one with dts@4: failed to load config from … error during build: Error: Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/core'
https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/2452
adding ajv to the dependencies did help with this: npm i ajv

In my case, I solved that issue by following:

Restarting IDE
Deleting tsconfig.json file
Initialising tsconfig.json using tsc --init
If above solutions did not work, try "jsx": "preserve"

